# If $G = \langle x,y\rangle$, then $\bar{G} = \langle\bar{x}, \bar{y}\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Problem 3.1.16 from Dummit and Foote. I dont know why I'm losing energy over this problem, but I'd just like verification.

> Let $G$ be a group, let $N$ be a normal subgroup and let $\bar{G} = G/N$. If $G = \langle x,y \rangle$, then $\bar{G} = \langle \bar{x},\bar{y}\rangle$.

Pick $\bar{g} \in \bar{G}$. Then $\bar{g} = gN = (s^{\epsilon_1}_1 ... s^{\epsilon_1}_1)N =s^{\epsilon_1}_1N...s^{\epsilon_n}_nN = r^{\delta_1}_1...r^{\delta_n}_n$ for $r_i \in \{xN, yN\} = \{\bar{x}, \bar{y}\}$.

$\implies \bar{g} \in \langle \bar{x}, \bar{y} \rangle$ and $\bar{G} \subset \langle \bar{x}, \bar{y} \rangle$

And the inclusion of $\langle \bar{x}, \bar{y} \rangle$ in $\bar{G}$ is easily seen form essentially the same generalization of $r^{\delta_n}_n \in \langle \bar{x}, \bar{y} \rangle$ is some $s^{\epsilon_n}_nN \in \bar{G}$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: It seems fine to me.

Comment: @Shaun appreciate it. sometimes I just need a sanity check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems fine to me. However, you could improve it by defining the $s_i^{\epsilon_i}$.